The location of the zeros of the "new" function $\Psi(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{n!^s}}$
Defining the Psi function as $$\Psi(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{n!^s}}$$ and by studying, from a numerical point of view, the location of the zeros in the complex plane up to $0<\Im(s)<150000$, I found that they are included in the strip $0<\Re(s)\leq 0.73$.
See my document on the zeros of the Psi function on the complex plane.
I was wondering if it could be demonstrated what the maximum value of $\Re(s)$ of the zeros of the $\Psi(s)$ function can be. Thank you.
R. Trocchi, The Psi function and its zeros on the complex plane, June 21 2024
See also: A373204 - OEIS.org
Addendum 1 - June 26 2024
In light of the comments received so far: also defining $$\Psi_0(s) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{n!^s}}$$ and calculating the zeros up to $0 < \Im(s) < 150000$, I found that they are included in the strip $0 < \Re(s) \leq 0.274689$.
I suppose now $\sigma := \Re(s)$ must be small enough that $2 < \sum_{n=2}^\infty n!^{-\sigma}$, so the upper bound is about $0.355953$.
Summing up:
$$0.726241 \leq \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Psi(s)=0\}} \leq 0.738881$$
$$0.274689 \leq \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Psi_0(s)=0\}} \leq 0.355953$$
In this PDF document the comparison graphs between the zeros of the two functions $\Psi(s)$ and $\Psi_0(s)$.
Addendum 2 - June 28 2024
Continuing to calculate the zeros of the function $\Psi(s)$ up to $\Im(s) \leq 2\cdot10^7$, for $0.72 \leq \Re(s) \leq 0.74$, I found that there is a decay in the distribution of zeros for $\Re(s) > 0.724$, see the histogram plot in this new PDF document:
The Psi(s) function zeros in 0.72<=Re(s)<=0.74, up to Im(s)<=2*10^7
I also found that zeros have $\Re(s) \leq 0.7263411$, which stands as new lower bound of the theoretical value sought:
$$0.726341 \leq \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Psi(s)=0\}} \leq 0.738881$$.
Addendum 3 - June 30 2024
Looking for zeros, with $s:=\sigma+i t$ :
$$\Psi(s)=0$$
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{e^{-s\log(n!)}}$$
taking real parts:
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{\Re(e^{-s\log(n!)})}$$
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{e^{-\sigma\log(n!)}\cos(-t\log(n!))}$$
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}\cos(t\log(n!))}$$
By calculating the coefficients $\cos(t\log(n!))$ for some zeros found in the "Addendum 2" section for $\Im(s)\leq2\cdot10^7$, I found that this following is the pattern of coefficients that repeats for zeros with a larger real part:



n
$\cos(t\log(n!))$




2
$\approx-1$


3
$\approx-1$


4
$\approx-1$


5
$\approx-1$


6
$\approx1$


7
$\approx-1$


8
$\approx1$


9
$\approx1$


10
$\approx-1$



With this pattern of coefficients we have:
$$-1=-2!^{-\sigma}-3!^{-\sigma}-4!^{-\sigma}-5!^{-\sigma}+6!^{-\sigma}-7!^{-\sigma}+8!^{-\sigma}+9!^{-\sigma}-10!^{-\sigma}$$
which gives as solution $\sigma_1 \approx 0.726344797$.
Considering the extra terms coefficients set to $-1$:
$$-1=-2!^{-\sigma}-3!^{-\sigma}-4!^{-\sigma}-5!^{-\sigma}+6!^{-\sigma}-7!^{-\sigma}+8!^{-\sigma}+9!^{-\sigma}-10!^{-\sigma} -\sum _{n=11}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}}$$
the solution is:
$$\sigma_t \approx 0.726347509$$
(Obviously, if all the coefficients were $-1$ then Professor Noam D. Elkies' upper bound would be found.)
Now the question is: is this pattern of coefficients the combination that determines the $\sup{\{\Re(s) : \Psi(s)=0\}}$ (to be proven) and $\sigma_t$ is the new upper bound, or is it simply a "relatively maximum" pattern due to the limitation of the evaluation of the zeros only up to to $\Im(s)\leq2\cdot10^7$ ?
The calculations in this PDF file.

For what $s$ does the series converge?

@GeraldEdgar I believe the series converges for $\Re(s)>0$. There seems to be a pair of zeros in the proximity of $0.642\pm i, 4.907$.

Certainly $\sigma := \mathop{\rm Re} s$ must be small enough that
$1 < \sum_{n=2}^\infty n!^{-\sigma}$; this comes to an upper bound of
about 0.73888.  If the $n!$ for $n \geq 2$ were multiplicatively independent,
that bound would be sharp; but dependences do exist, starting with
$2!^2 3! = 4!$ and $2!3!5!=6!$.  Those two dependences are OK because
in each case the counts of factors on the LHS and RHS have the same parity,
so we could still have $n!^{-s} \sim -1$ for $n \leq 6$;
but things get complicated starting with $2!^3 7! = 8!$.

Note that $\Psi(s)=(1,,{-}1)\left[\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n^{-s}&1\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right]
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Funnily, $\zeta(s)=(1,,{-}1)\left[\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&n^{-s}\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right]
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Nevertheless, I would start the sum at $n=0$, as then $\Psi(1)=e$ and $\Psi(2)=I_0(2)$. This would of course shift the zeroes.

To elaborate on the comment by @FredHucht, the following table illustrates the more general pattern for evaluation at $s\in\mathbb{N}$. $$\begin{array}{ccc}
s & \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n!)^{-s} & \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n!)^{-s} \
1 & e-1 & , _0F_0(;;1)=e \
2 & I_0(2)-1 & , _0F_1(;1;1)=I_0(2) \
3 & , _0F_2(;1,1;1)-1 & , _0F_2(;1,1;1) \
4 & , _0F_3(;1,1,1;1)-1 & , _0F_3(;1,1,1;1) \
5 & , _0F_4(;1,1,1,1;1)-1 & , _0F_4(;1,1,1,1;1) \
\end{array}$$

I have inserted the "Addendum 1" section.

I have inserted the "Addendum 2" section.

I have inserted the "Addendum 3" section.

July 06 2024
From the "Addendum 3" section, with $s:=\sigma+i t$
$$\Psi(s) = 0$$
$$-1 = \sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}\cos(t\log(n!))}$$
defining the coefficients:
$$C_n(t) := \cos(t\log(n!))$$
when
$$t(\log(n!)-\log((n-1)!)) = k_n(t) \pi$$
if $k_n(t)$ is a even integer then $C_n(t) = C_{n-1}(t)$
if $k_n(t)$ is a odd integer then $C_n(t) = -C_{n-1}(t)$
But from the definition of factorial $n! = (n-1)! \cdot n$
$$\log(n!) = \log((n-1)!) + \log n$$
so:
$$t\log n = k_n(t) \pi$$
$$k_n(t) := \frac{t\log n}{\pi}$$
Now suppose there exists a $t$ (very large, and so will the $k_n(t)$) such that we can construct the coefficients $C_n(t)$ so as to have the extreme case of $\sigma$ (highest value).
Ideally we would like all $C_n(t) = -1$ (see the Professor Noam D. Elkies' upper bound), but we will see that this cannot be achieved.
Let's start building them from low $n$, i.e. from the terms of the summation with the largest contribution.

$n=2$ (2 is prime so $k_2(t)$ is a "degree of freedom") Since $C_1(t) = +1$ and to have the worst case of higher sigma, i.e. $C_2(t) = -1$ then $k_2(t)$ must be an odd integer.
$n=3$ (3 is prime so $k_3(t)$ is a "degree of freedom") To have $C_3(t) = -1$ and being $C_2(t) = -1$ then it must be $k_3(t)$ an even integer.
$n=4$ Since $4=2^2$ then $k_4(t) = 2\cdot k_2(t)$ so it will be an even integer and therefore since $C_3(t) = -1$ then it will be $C_4(t) = -$1.
$n=5$ (5 is prime so $k_5(t)$ is a "degree of freedom") To have $C_5(t) = -1$ and being $C_4(t) = -1$ then it must be $k_5(t)$ an even integer.
$n=6$ Since $6=2\cdot3$ then $k_6(t) = k_2(t) + k_3(t)$ = odd + even = odd and therefore since $C_5(t) = -1$ then it will be $C_6 (t) = +1$.
$n=7$ (7 is prime so $k_7(t)$ is a "degree of freedom") To have $C_7(t) = -1$ and being $C_6(t) = +1$ then it must be $k_7(t)$ an odd integer.
$n=8$ Since $8=2^3$ then $k_8(t) = 3\cdot k_2(t)$ so it will be an odd integer and therefore since $C_7(t) = -1$ then it will be $C_8(t) = +$1.
$n=9$ Since $9=3^2$ then $k_9(t) = 2\cdot k_3(t)$ so it will be an even integer and therefore since $C_8(t) = +1$ then it will be $C_9(t) = +$1.
$n=10$ Since $10=2\cdot5$ then $k_{10}(t) = k_2(t) + k_5(t)$ = odd + even = odd and therefore since $C_9(t) = +1$ then will be $C_{10}(t) = -1$.

and so on...
This is the extreme case table up to $n=27$:



$n$
$k_n(t)$
$C_n(t)$
Factoriz.
Used $k_n$ rules




2
odd
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_2$


3
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_3$


4
even
$-1$
$4 = 2^2$
$k_4 = 2\cdot k_2$


5
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_5$


6
odd
$+1$
$6 = 2\cdot3$
$k_6 = k_2 + k_3$


7
odd
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_7$


8
odd
$+1$
$8 = 2^3$
$k_8 = 3\cdot k_2$


9
even
$+1$
$9 = 3^2$
$k_9 = 2\cdot k_3$


10
odd
$-1$
$10 = 2\cdot5$
$k_{10} = k_2 + k_5$


11
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_{11}$


12
even
$-1$
$12 = 2\cdot6$
$k_{12} = k_2 + k_6$


13
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_{13}$


14
even
$-1$
$14 = 2\cdot7$
$k_{14} = k_2 + k_7$


15
even
$-1$
$15 = 3\cdot5$
$k_{15} = k_3 + k_5$


16
even
$-1$
$16 = 2^4$
$k_{16} = 4\cdot k_2$


17
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_{17}$


18
odd
$+1$
$18 = 2\cdot9$
$k_{18} = k_2 + k_9$


19
odd
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_{19}$


20
even
$-1$
$20 = 4\cdot5$
$k_{20} = k_4 + k_5$


21
odd
$+1$
$21 = 3\cdot7$
$k_{21} = k_3 + k_7$


22
odd
$-1$
$22 = 2\cdot11$
$k_{22} = k_2 + k_{11}$


23
even
$-1$
prime
d.o.f. $k_{23}$


24
odd
$+1$
$24 = 2\cdot12$
$k_{24} = k_2 + k_{12}$


25
even
$+1$
$25 = 5^2$
$k_{25} = 2\cdot k_5$


26
odd
$-1$
$26 = 2\cdot13$
$k_{26} = k_2 + k_{13}$


27
even
$-1$
$27 = 3^3$
$k_{27} = 3\cdot k_3$



...
In summary, the rules for constructing $C_n(t)$ in the extreme case are:
with $C_1(t) = 1$
if $k_n(t)$ is a even integer then $C_n(t) = C_{n-1}(t)$
if $k_n(t)$ is a odd integer then $C_n(t) = -C_{n-1}(t)$
starting from $n=2$

if $n$ is prime then $k_n(t)$ is an integer "degree of freedom":



if $C_{n-1}(t) = -1$ then an even integer $k_n(t)$ will be needed to have $C_n(t) = C_{n-1}(t) = -1$
if $C_{n-1}(t) = +1$ then $k_n(t)$ will be needed as an odd integer to have $C_n(t) = -C_{n-1}(t) = -1$



if $n$ is composed of $n = q_1^{e_1} q_2^{e_2} \cdot\cdot\cdot q_r^{e_r}$, then the formula follows (from $k_n(t)$ definition):
$$k_n(t) = \sum _{m=1}^{r}{e_m\cdot k_{q_m}(t)}$$
so it is simple to calculate whether $k_n(t)$ is an even or odd integer, and calculate $C_n(t)$ from $C_{n-1}(t)$.

These extreme case rules demonstrate why the pattern observed in the zero-finding numerical calculations is as in the table in the "Addendum 3" section.
So the exact answer to the question:
$$\sigma_{sup} := \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Psi(s)=0\}}$$
will be the solution to the equation:
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
with the $C_n(t)$ coefficients calculated with the rules representing the extreme case (in the table the values up to $n=27$).
Numerically, solving the:
$$-1 = -2!^{-\sigma}-3!^{-\sigma}-4!^{-\sigma}-5!^{-\sigma}+6!^{-\sigma}-7!^{-\sigma}+8!^{-\sigma}+9!^{-\sigma}-\sum_{n=10}^{17}{n!^{-\sigma}}+18!^{-\sigma}-19!^{-\sigma}-20!^{-\sigma}+\sum_{n=21}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
the solution is:
$$\sigma_{sup} \approx 0.726347508576$$
This confirms also my numerical search for $\Psi(s)$ zeros, carried out in the area $0 < \Im(s) \leq 10^9$, where the zero with the largest $\Re(s)$ part that I found is:
$$s_{max} \approx 0.726346524 + i\cdot 928745093.078332215$$.
In the following PDF file the calculation of $\sigma_{sup}$ and the table in the case of zero $s_{max}$.
$\Psi_0$ function case section - July 07 2024
In the case of $\Psi_0(s)$ function, defined in the "Addendum 1" section, the exact solution to the question:
$$\sigma_{sup0} := \sup( \Re(s) : \Psi_0(s)=0 )$$
is the solution of the equation:
$$-2 = \sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
with the same $C_n(t)$ coefficients calculated with the rules representing the extreme case.
Numerically, solving the:
$$-2 = -2!^{-\sigma}-3!^{-\sigma}-4!^{-\sigma}-5!^{-\sigma}+6!^{-\sigma}-7!^{-\sigma}+8!^{-\sigma}+9!^{-\sigma}-\sum _{n=10}^{17}{n!^{-\sigma}}+18!^{-\sigma}-19!^{-\sigma}-20!^{-\sigma}+\sum _{n=21}^{\infty }{n!^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
the solution is:
$$\sigma_{sup0} \approx 0.275793268746$$
This confirms also my numerical search for $\Psi_0(s)$ zeros, carried out in the $0 < \Im(s) \leq 150000$ zone, where the zero with the largest $\Re(s)$ part that I found is:
$$s_{max0} \approx 0.274688787 + i\cdot 81967.679299613$$
Octave script files
These Octave script files calculate the $C_n(t)$ coefficients in the extreme case and the $\sigma_{sup}$ and $\sigma_{sup0}$ values:
Psi_Psi0___sigma_sup.m
f_opt_real.m
